# Clone repo into existing directory with dependencies installed

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, electron

Right now, I'm working on a project that I've put on GitHub in order to manage code sharing with other people I'm working with. I'm completely new to GitHub, and so far all I've been doing is opening VSCode, selecting "Clone repository", cloning my repo, making edits, and finally pushing all changes to the master branch.

The project I'm working on is an electron app, and after making edits I'd like to be able to run the app and test out any changes I've made. To do this, it seems like I'd have to reinstall electron in the newly created repository folder every time I clone the repo.

Is there a way to either

1. take the files from the repo and put them into a folder with electron already installed (without messing up VSCode's directory traversal/record of what's in the repo) or
2. include node_modules or something similar in the repo so that a full electron reinstall in the repo folder isn't necessary?

Comment: You shouldn't need to clone the repository more than once. From that point on, you just work in the existing directory.

Comment: If changes are made by another person, will said changes propagate to my local copy of the repo without a reclone? That's the only reason I'm currently recloning every time I start a new work session.

Comment: That's what the `git pull` command is for. In VSCode, there is a "down arrow" when viewing the repository in the source control panel that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem was to simply reinstall electron as a global dependency. The original global install seemed to not be working, and reinstalling as a global makes it available in every folder as opposed to just one. This removes the need to move files around from one folder to another.